# SharePoint online File archiving

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Is there a way to use Labels and Policies to Move documents that were not modified in 7 years to a Library on a different site?
I see the ability to set documents as records or delete them after a time period, but not archive them.
Alternatively is there another way to accomplish this, in Sharepoint online?

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is achievable with Microsoft Flow.

Trigger the Flow on a Date column and use “Copy file” and “Delete file” actions to move the documents to the target location.

Here’s an article with detailed steps for a Flow for your reference.

[A MODERN “TRANSFER TO ANOTHER LOCATION” IN OFFICE 365.](https://joannecklein.com/2018/01/02/a-modern-transfer-to-another-location-in-office-365/)